# Barbie Pet Rescue PC game Windows 10 problem

Tags: windows-10, barbie-pet-rescue

I downloaded Barbie Pet Rescue on Windows 10 and I completed the setup and I also run this program in compatibility mode for which I picked Windows 95. I also picked:

- Reduce color mode: 16-bit (65536) Color
- Run in 640 x 480 screen resolution
- Run this program as Administrator.

It worked, but the audio is not clear and the screen resolution is very small. So, how can I fix the screen resolution and fix the audio in Barbie Pet Rescue game?

Comment: Why run it in compatibility mode? Also, you said you had the screen resolution set to something implying you know how to change it.

Comment: Barbie Pet Rescue does not support Windows 7/8/10 so issues are to be expected. It's designed for a much older version of Windows so you might have more luck running it in a virtual machine. As for the resolution issue - you have chosen to run it in compatibility mode at a resolution of 640x480 so your resolution is set to 640x480 and you can not change it.